# .NET Web App compilation on first request

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, cil, .net-runtime

I have a short question, once I deployed my Web App to IIS and when i make a first request it is compiled to CIL and stored in "\Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder. After that first request, is there a full compiled app or only used part of it?

I have read a lot of articles about that but that is not clear enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on compilation settings in web.config it either all views/pages will be compiled or only views that used to render pages.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Did You ever used that settings? Can You tell more about it ? 
I would be grateful
EDIT: I found this, i should read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.85).aspx, if i will have more questions, i will be asking here :)

Comment: I have another question regarding this one above, if i set batch compilation in web config to compile whole app on first request, is there a posibility to find somewhere  error description in case of failure ?